# ValueError: Invalid coordinate dimensionality

Tags: python, geojson, geometry, geopandas, shapely

I have looked for this error everywhere. Shapely did not provide anything about it.

What I am trying to do is convert multiple LineStrings into Multilinestring and convert it back to one LineString with ops.linemerge

```
list_lines = '''[ LINESTRING Z (106.859360409289 43.0466887338676 -90.3134785987513,
        106.859493724627 43.0466608020767 -90.08756605785879),
        LINESTRING Z (106.860395798461 43.0474727994385 -90.70117552089501,
        106.860856566526 43.0479333434232 -92.32231714313539) ]'''

multi_line = geometry.MultiLineString(list_lines)

ValueError: Invalid coordinate dimensionality
```

Answer (score 3):

With your script the result of `list_lines` is a string, and you cannot create a shapely MultiLineString with strings

a) With a simple list of WKT strings (and not a string with lists):

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiLineString
list_lines = ['LINESTRING Z (106.859360409289 43.0466887338676 -90.3134785987513,106.859493724627 43.0466608020767 -90.08756605785879)]','LINESTRING Z (106.860395798461 43.0474727994385 -90.70117552089501,106.860856566526 43.0479333434232 -92.32231714313539)']
# convert WKT strings to shapely geometries
from shapely.wkt import loads
list_lines = [loads(i) for i in list_lines]
# MultLineString
multi_line = MultiLineString(list_lines)
print(multi_line)
MULTILINESTRING Z ((106.859360409289 43.0466887338676 -90.3134785987513, 106.859493724627 43.0466608020767 -90.08756605785879), (106.860395798461 43.0474727994385 -90.70117552089501, 106.860856566526 43.0479333434232 -92.32231714313539))

for geom in multi_line:
   print(geom)
LINESTRING Z (106.859360409289 43.0466887338676 -90.3134785987513, 106.859493724627 43.0466608020767 -90.08756605785879)
LINESTRING Z (106.860395798461 43.0474727994385 -90.70117552089501, 106.860856566526 43.0479333434232 -92.32231714313539)
```

b) Convert it back to one LineString with ops.linemerge

```
 from shapely import ops
 merged_line = ops.linemerge(multi_line)
 print(merged_line)
 MULTILINESTRING Z ((106.859360409289 43.0466887338676 -90.3134785987513, 106.859493724627 43.0466608020767 -90.08756605785879), (106.860395798461 43.0474727994385 -90.70117552089501, 106.860856566526 43.0479333434232 -92.32231714313539))
```

if your lines aren't contiguous, the result is a MultiLineString (see [shapely.ops.linemerge](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html?highlight=linemerge#shapely.ops.linemerge))

Your lines in 2D:

[image]